# "takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given" error

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-functions

I'm running the python script below on Google Cloud Functions. When testing the script I have the following error:

`Error: function terminated. Recommended action: inspect logs for termination reason. Details:
run() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given`

What does it mean?

Here is my script:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

client = bigquery.Client()

def run():
    csv_file = six.BytesIO(b"""full_name,age
Phred Phlyntstone,32
Wylma Phlyntstone,29
""")

    table_ref = dataset.table('ga-online-audit:test_python.test')
    job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig()
    job_config.source_format = 'CSV'
    job_config.skip_leading_rows = 1
    job = client.load_table_from_file(
        csv_file, table_ref, job_config=job_config)  # API request
    job.result()  # Waits for table load to complete.
```

As I'm learning I took this script from the following documentation https://google-cloud-python.readthedocs.io/en/0.32.0/bigquery/usage.html

Comment: How are you calling `run`? The error description is pretty clear: `run` accepts 0 arguments but is being passed one by whatever is calling it.

Comment: I've past the name of my function in the function to execute field in Google Cloud Function. I'm running my function using the testing trigger.

Comment: I'm not familiar at all with `google.cloud`, but I'm guessing google is passing some kind of `event` object to your run function. Someone with more knowledge can build off of this, but in order to figure out exactly what the hack is going on, I would modify `run` to accept a single argument and `print` the value of that argument right away to see what it looks like.

Comment: I suggest stripping this down to the minimum code that recreates the issue.  If you remove all traces of bigquery, I think you will still have the same problem.  So, please do the following: **edit the question to show the minimal code, and also show how you are deploying this function with gcloud**.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: but if I'm removing traces of BigQuery, there is nothing left no? The only thing which is not bigquery related is the csv_file variable. and like I said the function is deployed through Google Cloud Functions.

Comment: Stripping it down to the minimum would involve simply adding a log line to tell you that the function executed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you have posted all of your code, it's apparent that something else is calling your function.  Looking at a Google Cloud Function [example](https://medium.com/@timhberry/getting-started-with-python-for-google-cloud-functions-646a8cddbb33) in python, it looks like your function must be defined so that it takes at least one argument.

The code in the linked article has `def hello_world(request)`, in this case, `request` is the argument that is passed when you call the cloud function.  AWS Lambdas are similar, in that they pack any URL parameters or JSON payload from the client into this `request` argument, so that's likely what's going on here.

I would recommend adding an argument to the definition of `run`.  This will fix your error, and inspecting the argument will give you insight on what kind of information the Google cloud function platform is automatically sending to your code.

Comment: I have past my entire code in the question so no run(arg) I guess.

Comment: Since that's all of your code, it's apparent that Google Cloud is calling your function and expects it to take an argument.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: Adding up the argument crashes when running locally. How to execute locally?

Comment: @Augusto, can you create a new question with details of what you're trying to do?  I'm not sure how you're setting up the lambda/cloud function to execute locally, but it's likely that you'll need to mock the `request` object that is normally passed in by the AWS/GCP environment.

Comment: @rnorris I have created one, could please check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72863004/error-in-route-execution-on-flask-missing-1-required-positional-argument-go