# Error in route execution on Flask: "missing 1 required positional argument" - Google Cloud Function

Tags: python, flask, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

Developing a simple function to be deployed in the Google Cloud Function, a detail has come up. When using a parameter `request` as a function's argument, the code is not executed locally but is executed in cloud env. When not using `request` as an argument the code works fine locally but crashes in the cloud env.

- `def hello_http(request):` not works locally / works fine in cloud
- `def hello_http():` works fine locally / not works in cloud

Current state running locally:

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import auth
import flask
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
firebase_admin.initialize_app()

@app.route('/hello_http', methods=['GET'])
def hello_http(request):
    if 'token' in request.args:
        uid = validate(request)
        if uid == False:
            return 401
        else:            
            response = flask.jsonify({'UID': uid})
            print('Headers: ' + str(response.headers))
            print('UID: ' + str(uid))
            return response
    else:
        return 'bad request!', 400

def validate(request):
    try:
        decoded_token = auth.verify_id_token(request.args['token'], check_revoked=True)
        uid = decoded_token['uid']
        return uid
    except Exception as e:
        return False

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Invocation:

`curl -XGET "http://127.0.0.1:5000/hello_http?token=2"`

Output:

```
[2022-07-04 21:13:00,234] ERROR in app: Exception on /hello_http [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/agstcadini/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/agstcadini/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/Users/agstcadini/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_cors/extension.py", line 165, in wrapped_function
    return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
  File "/Users/agstcadini/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Users/agstcadini/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Users/agstcadini/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/agstcadini/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
TypeError: hello_http() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'
```

Comment: Try to replace your route like `@app.route('/hello_http/<token>', methods=['GET'])`.

Comment: **def hello_http():** is correct for both local and Cloud Run. There is something else wrong with your environment. Which version of Flask are you using locally and in Cloud Run?

Comment: @JohnHanley I have set flask 2.1.2 in requirements.txt. Sounds like in cloud env. some argument must be passed, what not happen locally. If I can discover that argument I'd add it to local requests.

Comment: No argument is required in your example. Something else is wrong.  Note: Python is very sensitive to indenting. Update your example code to be correct.

Comment: @JohnHanley I have updated with whole code.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it work either with GCP and locally in simple way. You should just add one more function which will be called only by local environment and it will trigger `hello_http(request)`.

As for your example, i would just add the marked lines:

```
@app.route('/hello_http', methods=['GET'])
def run (): # Add this line
    hello_http(request) # Add this line

def hello_http(request):
    if 'token' in request.args:
        uid = validate(request)

[...]
```

In this setting your `--entry-point` on the gcloud deploy command should stay `hello_http`: `gcloud functions deploy YOUR_FUNCTION_NAME --entry-point=hello_http` (for more information - [link](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/deploy))